# Acute Triangulation of 2D Polygonal domains

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, cgal, triangulation

Does Cgal have a built in option to triangulate a 2D Polygonal domain (say with holes) such the all triangles are acute? I am aware of the program aCute, but am wondering if Cgal can do this.

If there is a friendly version of aCute in Java or Mathematica, I will be happy to use it as well.

Thank you in advance!
Saar

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TriangulateMesh.html

Comment: Thank you, Chris! I am familiar  TriangulateMesh (and its many generalizations) in Wolfram. However, to the best of my knowledge, none of the options in TriangulateMesh guarantees that the triangulation given will consist of only acute triangles (I can send you examples where it fails to do so). The option MeshCellQaulity (which I also tried) was not strong enough to have all the triangles acute. If I am missing something, please let me know. I need this for an actual research project and thus far have been using aCute. Saar

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say that but CGAL does not have an algorithm to create such acute 2D triangulations.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I was looking around a the many options that CGAL provides and was hopeful to find this one. Just for the sake of sharing, these kind of (acute) triangulations are essential in applications related to PDE.

It would be great if one day you can have this option for 2D planar domain as well as for polyhedral (no-planar) domains. Saar